# Как установить pyinstaller на питон?

Tags: python

У меня есть проект на питон. И мне нужно установить pyintaller. Но когда я пишу pip install pyinstaller возникает ошибка:
pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

- ```
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить develop версию pyinstaller.

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```

У меня только эта версия установилась